# How to change the text label of UIButton click (touch) event?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, uibutton

I am new to iOS development with SDK version 5.0 through XCode. In my application I need to change the title of my Button when is push it.

Suppose in normal state it is "unpushed". All what I need is that when I push it the button label should change to "pushed".

Hoping to get help soon!

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you.

```
[btn setTitle:@"Pushed" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btn setTitle:@"UnPushed" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the button action add the following code - 
[Button setTitle:@"Pushed"];

Answer (score 0):

```
     -(IBAction)startSomething:(id)sender {
            [sender setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
}
```

Or if you're wanting to toggle the name of the button, you can create a BOOL named "buttonToggled" (for example), and toggle the name this way:

```
-(IBAction)toggleButton:(id)sender {
    if (!buttonToggled) {
        [sender setTitle:@"Unpushed" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buttonToggled = YES;
    }
    else {
        [sender setTitle:@"pushed" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buttonToggled = NO;
    } }
```

Answer (score 0):

please see the [Control States](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIControlStateSelected)

you can do it like this:

```
[button setTitle:@"pushed" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```